# Both :nth-child and :last-child

Tags: css

Code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td colspan="2"></td>    <==== Only this
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td colspan="3"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to select only the fourth "td" but only if it's the last. Can I do this?

```
tr td:last-child:nth-child(4) { /* Some Style  */ }
```

Comment: That should work as you have it.

Comment: Yes, you can: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9TF8/)

Comment: What's going on here? Either you didn't try your own code before posting the question, or you have abstracted your actual problem away by simplifying it too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can

```
tr td:last-child:nth-child(4) { background: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VnbTv/)

```
tr td:nth-of-type(4):last-child {
    /*some code here*/
     }
```

Or

```
tr td:nth-child(4):last-child {
    background-color: red;
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it is not possible.If you want to make it work then you can add a specific `class` or `id` with your desire `td` element.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    if($(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").is(':last-child')) {
     $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").css("color","red");   
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WDx8Z/)

Comment: Is there some invisible jQuery tag on this question?